# Sonarqube 5.3 - Unable to register extension

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube5.3

I have recently upgraded to 5.3 in order to have a look at the SQALE 2.7 Plugin but have been having issues since:

> 08-Mar-2016 13:49:03   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX-XXX: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor: Lorg/sonar/api/checks/NoSonarFilter;: org.sonar.api.checks.NoSonarFilter -> [Help 1]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, check this one out:

[Jenkins sonar check failure: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.checks.NoSonarFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030512/jenkins-sonar-check-failure-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-so)

Basically, what they have as a problem is that SonarQube 5.3+ has a different code from the plugin that you try to run on (3.0.1). For me, the combination of SonarQube 5.6 and 3.0.2/3.0.1 still doesn't fix it, so I guess you can wait for that or try to disable JavaSquid.